# How to change a file inside an archive (.ear) file without extracting entire file

Tags: linux, file, archive, binaryfiles, ear

I have an `.ear` file (an archive file like tar / zip) that has a file inside that i want to change.

For example `myfile.ear` contains `1.txt` and i want to change `1.txt` to `2.txt` and possibly also change some of the content inside `1.txt` (like `sed` does)

I really want to avoid having to extract `myfile.ear`, change the file and compress it again.

Does anyone know a way to achieve this in linux ?

And if it's not possible, I would also like to know why

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EAR files are just JAR files which are just ZIP files.  The ZIP format, IIRC, contains metadata and data interleaved, so changing one file (which might be larger/smaller than the file it is replacing) might not fit (or leave a gap), thus in all practical terms the file must be rewritten when doing modifications.

Comment: is it possible then to extact only the specific file, modify it and put it back again ? or do i have to recompress everything again ?

Comment: Any ZIP util I've ever used recreates the archive with those kinds of modifications.