# Edit file without unzipping archive

Tags: linux, bash, php-ziparchive

How do i edit file without unzipping archive, reason is i am writing automation task, I can do unzip, edit file and zip it, But it would be good if i can do it in runtime so it will save time to unzip/zip.

Comment: Duplicate question. You can't do that see below:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334037/how-to-change-a-file-inside-an-archive-ear-file-without-extracting-entire-fil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`zip` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zip) provides a `-u` option to update a zip archive. You can use it like so:

```
zip -u bigzip.zip file/to/update1 file/to/update2 ...
```

---

It won't be instant, but it will be a lot faster. If I create a sample 200MB zip file:

```
mkdir source
for (( f = 0; f < 200; f++ )); do
    head -c 1000000 /dev/random > source/${f}
done
zip -0r bigzip.zip source
```

then unzipping, editing one file, and rezipping takes about 9s on my machine:

```
unzip bigzip.zip
head -c 1000000 /dev/random > source/3
zip -0r bigzip.zip source
```

but it takes only about 3s to call `zip -u`.

```
mkdir source
head -c1000000 /dev/random > source/3
zip -u bigzip.zip source/3
```

Comment: This script `zip  -u file.zip path-to-file-1 path-to-file-2 ...` does not work for me with python3. Is there any trick that I need to follow?